# How to search function using the description of this function?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to find necessary function by writing some key words or phrase from description of needed function. This need in cases, when I dont remember the name of function, but I know what it must do.

For examle: I want to produce sequence from two sequences. But I dont remember the function name.
Needed function called "Zip". This function has description with my wishes.
[image: String.Zip]

Only what I can is to search my wishes using the sources, like Google, StackOverflow and so on. I think that Visual Studio has all opportunities to find function using only its description.

But I dont know how to do this. It would be cool to find all the functions contain needed request in description and I could choose the fitting in my case.

Comment: Visual studio does not include search capabilities for the comment section. You can search in the comments with the global search in visual studio for methods, classes .. etc for which the source code is part of the current project you have opened.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do so using reflection. Add descriptions to each method like [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.8)
Then, you can use the GetCustomAttributes class method to get a list of descriptions:

```
var descriptions = (DescriptionAttribute[])
            nameOfClass.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
```

You can iterate through your descriptions to find the correct methods to call, and you can also do this through reflection like so:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = nameOfClass.GetMethod(methodName);
object result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
```

I am sure you will want to do more error checking and handling, but this at least explains how to go about doing this.

You can then search for your methods based on how the descriptions match. I'm not how you prefer to go about doing so, but I'd be happy to help.

Comment: This won't help for searching descriptions for methods which are part of the framework. Generally this is not a solution. The description attribute is used to add info for visual designers - win forms for example.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski I understand now. I misread his question. This was a solution to the wrong question.